# How to get a specific array value from an XML File?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have written an xml-parser to read an XML-file. The XML-file is not mine so I can't change the structure. Things work great till I got to this special point. I want to read a value but I don't have a key to access this value. 
I marked the values (in red) in the screenshot below which I want to access.

[image]

When I dump the parent element (the **PRAT->VALUE**) I get this in return:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#31 (3) { ["@attributes"]=> array(5) { ["nr"]=> string(1) "1" ["unit"]=> string(3) "bar" ["unit_id"]=> string(4) "3103" ["vo"]=> string(0) "" ["vo_id"]=> string(0) "" } [0]=> string(2) "20" [1]=> string(1) "2" }
```

As seen, at the end of the dump the values that I want to access are presented. I tried to access it like an array but that doesn't work. The values are not part of the **attributes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use (String) keyword in front of it.

eg.

```
echo (String) PRAT->VALUE;
```

Comment: HA! That works! Thank you! Can you explain why the dump shows an array and why I have to convert it to a string?

Comment: as it says it returns object(SimpleXMLElement) rather than string.
(String) converts the value to String